# How to replicate useState with vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

What would be the implementation for the code in Vanilla JS that allows us to declare and update state like the way useState does so in React:

```
const [x, setX] = useState(12);
setX(14);
console.log(x); // 14
```

This question is strictly get better at JS. Naively it would make sense to go with:

```
// Solution 1

function update(value, newValue) {
    value = newValue;
    return value;
}

function state(value) {
    return [ value, update ];
}

let [value, setValue] = state(12)
value = setValue(value, 14)
console.log(value); // 14


// Solution 2

class State {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    
    update(newValue) {
        this.value = newValue;
    }
}

const x = new State(12);
x.update(14);
console.log(x.value); // 14
```

But I don't understand how the array [x, setX] has a callback (setX) that can affect x when declared with a const? I hope that makes sense.

Comment: here is a good resource to read https://www.newline.co/@CarlMungazi/a-journey-through-the-usestate-hook--a4983397 There is a bit of js-magic under the hood

Answer (score 11):

I wanted to learn how to accomplish this as well. ***[I found how to do it here](https://codesandbox.io/s/ff4rx?file=/src/index.js:673-756)***. I refactored the code to use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead, which can make the code snippet harder to read & understand. If it's the case, head to the resources shared in the link above.

This is the implementation:

```js
const useState = (defaultValue) => {
  //  We create a function useState with a default value
  let value = defaultValue;
  //  We create a local variable value = defaultValue
  const getValue = () => value
  //  We create a function to set the value with parameter newValue
  const setValue = newValue => value = newValue //  We change the value for newValue
  return [getValue, setValue]; //  We return an array with the value and the function
}

const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
//  We destructure the array as a return of the useState function into two value

console.log(counter()); //  returns 0 which it's the value of counter()
```

I added the comments for easier understanding. This is the implementation withouth the comments:

```js
const useState = (defaultValue) => {
  let value = defaultValue;
  const getValue = () => value
  const setValue = newValue => value = newValue
  return [getValue, setValue];
}

const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

console.log(counter());
```

For better reading & understanding, I have included the snippet using [regular functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#function_declarations):

```js
function useState(defaultValue) {
  let value = defaultValue

  function getValue() {
    return value
  }

  function setValue(newValue) {
    value = newValue
  }

  return [getValue, setValue];
}

const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
```

Comment: Why is getValue a function why do not return the value directly?

Comment: I tried doing that but it takes the value at the time of initialisation only which is 0. Only after we fetch it via a function do we get the updated value from the function.

Answer (score 5):

There is something very important you are missing - all react hooks use something "backing" them which allows you to provide what are effectively instance variables when you don't have an instance, you only have a function.

This thing in React is called a fiber and it effectively represents the lifecycle of a React component - it's not tied to the function itself, per se, it's tied to the component react is rendering (and re-rendering). Which is why you can have one functional component declaration, render that same function multiple times, and each of those will be able to maintain their own state - the state isn't part of the function, the state is part of the React fiber.

> But I don't understand how the array [x, setX] has a callback (setX)
> that can affect x when declared with a const?

**You aren't simply mutating the value of x when you call `setX`, what you are doing is telling React to re-render the component (fiber) with a new value for x.**

EDIT:

A tremendously simplistic example, where the function itself is used as the backing instance of state (which is not the case in React) could look something like this:

```js
// this line is example only so we can access the stateSetter external to the function
let stateSetter;

const states = new Map();

const useState = (value,context) => {
    const dispatch = v => {
            const currentState = states.get(context.callee);
            currentState[0] = typeof v === 'function' ? v(currentState[0]) : v        
            // we re-call the function with the same arguments it was originally called with - "re-rendering it" of sorts...
            context.callee.call(context);    
    }
    const current = states.get(context.callee) || [value,dispatch];
    states.set(context.callee,current);
    return current;

}

const MyFunction = function(value) {
    const [state,setState] = useState(value, arguments)
    stateSetter = setState;
    console.log('current value of state is: ',state)
}

MyFunction(10);
MyFunction(20); // state hasn't changed
stateSetter('new state'); // state has been updated!
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this snippet. That's exactly what I've been looking for! Most other approaches seemed to be a complicated way of re-assigning to a variable only

Answer (score 0):

1.- Destructuring for values returned by a function.

- We apply it to destructure two values of an array
  returned in a function.
- The first value will return the current data of a variable and the second one will have the change function for said value.

```js
// Main function useState (similar to react Hook)
function useState(value){
  // Using first func to simulate initial value
  const getValue = () => {
    return value;
  };

  // The second function is to return the new value
  const updateValue = (newValue) => {
    // console.log(`Value 1 is now: ${newValue}`);
    return value = newValue;
  };

  // Returning results in array
  return [getValue, updateValue];
}

// Without destructuring
const initialValue = useState(3);
const firstValue = initialValue[0];
const secondValue = initialValue[1];

// Set new data
console.log("Initial State", firstValue()); // 3
console.log("Final", secondValue(firstValue() + 5)); // 8

console.log("===========================");

// With destructuring
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
console.log("Initial State", counter()); // 0
setCounter(counter() + 20);
console.log("Final", counter());
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
class useState {
    constructor(defaultt=""){ 
        this.state = { value: defaultt}
        const handler = {
                set: () => {
                    return false
                }
            }
        const data = new Proxy(this.state,handler);
        const stateBind = this.setState.bind(this)
        return [data, stateBind];
    }
    setState(variable){
        this.state.value = variable
    }
}

const [like,setLike] = new useState(0)
console.log(like.value) // 0
like.value=2;
console.log(like.value) // 0
setLike(like.value + 1) 
console.log(like.value) // 1
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution to mock the `useState()` using a constructor. This may not be the best solution as the constructor returns a copy of the function every time but achieves the problem in question.

```
function Hook(){
  return function (initialState){
    this.state = initialState;
    return [
      this.state,
      function(newState){
        this.state = newState;
      }
    ];
  }
}
const useState = new Hook();
```

Now, destructure the `useState()` which is an instace of `Hook()`

```
const [state, setState] = useState(0);
console.log(state); // 0
setState({x:20});
console.log(state); // { x: 20 }
setState({x:30});
console.log(state); // { x: 30 }
```

Comment: Not working it returns same initial value