# Jest - Pass mocked instance as class constructor argument

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm currently trying to write some test with jest (newbie). Regarding to my latest [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64893795/how-to-achieve-a-maintainable-reactive-ui-with-vanilla-js), I've got the following situation:

I've got multiple price fields. Each price field has its own renderer. A renderer has a reference to its pricefield. A pricefield can determine some html snippet from the dom.

```js
// priceField.js

class PriceField {
  constructor() {
    const renderer = new PriceFieldRenderer(this);
    // do something with renderer
  }

  /**
   * Determines Node in DOM for this price field
   */
  determinePriceFieldNode() {
    return document.querySelector(".price-field");
  }
}

export default PriceField;

// priceFieldRenderer.js

class PriceFieldRenderer {
  constructor(priceField) {
    this.priceFieldNode = priceField.determinePriceFieldNode();
  }
}

export default PriceFieldRenderer;
```

Now I want to test `PriceFieldRenderer` (with jest). Therefore, I need to mock `PriceField` and its `determinePriceFieldNode()` function.

However, I'm not able to pass a mocked price field instance as constructor argument. I've read the official documentation with its sound-player example and googled about 2 hours. Also i tested different implementations, but I'm not able to solve it. Here is one code snippet which throws following error: `TypeError: priceField.determinePriceFieldNode is not a function`

```js
jest.mock("./priceField");

import PriceFieldRenderer from "./priceFieldRenderer";
import PriceField from "./priceField";

describe("Price field renderer", () => {
  test("with calculated price", () => {
    const priceField = PriceField.mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        determinePriceFieldNode: () => "<html/>"
      };
    });

    const sut = new PriceFieldRenderer(priceField);

    expect(sut).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

I'm sure the way I did is not the best and there is some help out there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `priceField` is lowercase and makes an assumption that it's an instance, while it's spy function that should create an instance. It can be fixed with:

```
PriceField.mockImplementation(...);
const priceField = new PriceField();
const sut = new PriceFieldRenderer(priceField);
```

`priceField` module mock and and associated `PriceField` spy serve no good purpose. They would be needed if it were imported and used in another module, this is [the said example](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks) from Jest documentation shows.

That `PriceFieldRenderer` uses dependency injection makes testing simpler, this is one of benefits of the pattern:

```
const priceField = { determinePriceFieldNode: jest.fn(() => "<html/>") });
const sut = new PriceFieldRenderer(priceField);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I came across a similiar solution regarding to following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50108368/4065938):

`PriceField.prototype.determinePriceFieldNode = jest.fn().mockImplementation(...)`

However, your hint with the depencey injection is pretty nice!

Comment: You're welcome. FWIW, `PriceField.prototype.determinePriceFieldNode = jest.fn()` is an antipattern, it prevents a method from being restored, `jest.spyOn` should be used on existing objects as a rule of thumb.